# How to add an animation to the UIView in viewDidAppear?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I tried to add a animation to viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"transition" context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:self.view cache:YES];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and I think I found the solution on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250814/why-does-viewdidload-wait-before-updating-the-ui).

When viewDidAppear gets called you still don't see anything on the screen (despite the name), but you are about to. You can then use a performSelector:withDelay or an NSTimer to launch your animation. The delay can just be 0.1 and your animation will play just when the screen appears.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"View did appear!");

    [self performSelector:@selector(animationCode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

- (void)animationCode {
    // you animation code
}
```

Comment: I read a lot of articles before. And only this happend me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the view which state it should animate to so it won't do anything. You need to place code between `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations` that changes the appearance of the view (e.g. by removing one subview and adding another).

Comment: Hm, I think I dont need to tell him this. I tried my code into a IBAction and it works. I wrote setAnimationTransition: forView:
so I wrote in that the animation should be in the own view. It just doesn't work in the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear-methode.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not using `beginAnimations:` and `commitAnimations` correctly. You're supposed to put something in between them that normally wouldn't be animated: e.g. with `self.view.alpha = 0.5` you get a fading effect. **They have no effect on anything that isn't between them.**
2. By the time `viewDidAppear:` is called, your view, well... has appeared. It's too late to animate anything. What you actually want to do is something like this:

   ```
   - (void)showMyViewWithAnimation {
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:childView cache:YES];
       [parentView addSubview:childView];
       [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
   ```

   In the example above, `childView` is what in your example is called `self.view`.
3. Please write out the name of the transition; no one knows what 110 is by looking at it. It's bad style. </pedantry>

Comment: The bug in that code is that you should be doing `setAnimationTransition:forView:` on `self.view`, not `drum.view`. In the docs, it says: "Set the transition on the container view."

Comment: But i want the effect for the drum.view ;) Thats the reason, why I tried to get the animation into the viewDidLoad of the drumViewController.