# UIView Animation Not Working when pressed Back button

Tags: ios

I have 2 View controller. The first view controller contained 1 uiview with animation once the view controller is execute and a button "Proceed".
The 2nd view controller only contain 1 button which is "Back" button.

Situation:

when clicked on execute the uiview was animate well, after that proceed to 2nd view controller. when clicked on "Back" button on 2nd view controller and it dismiss and back to 1st view controller, the uiview not perform animation anymore.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [self.MainV setFrame:CGRectMake(10,370, 285, 73)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Are you animating the dismissing of the previous view controller? Perhaps those animations are colliding...

Comment: Never mind. I think I found a potential answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4908191/2274694

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever reset the MainV frame to where it started? Once the view has been animated into location once, it'll stay there. Maybe you want to move the MainV to a different location in the `-UIViewController viewDidDisappear]` method? You can set the frame of the view there so that it reanimate every time the view comes into view.

Comment: I have added this code but still nothing appear when clicked on back button-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    
    [self.MainV setFrame:CGRectMake(-300, 370, 285, 73)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    
   
    
}

Comment: Did you add it to your first view controller, and not the second?

Comment: ya. is at my first view controller.

Comment: Is there other code that's manipulating the frame of MainV? Maybe setting the reference to nil somewhere?